# Deep clone a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an object of objects:

```
nestedObj = {obj1:
{cat:'thing1', 
 scale: d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateGreens)},
 ...
}
```

And then I iterate over an array of things to create objects that are otherwise duplicative:

```
things = ['thing1','thing2',...]
// A loop that creates:
nestedObj.obj2 = Object.assign({},nestedObj.obj1,{cat:thing2}}
```

Then later in my code, I set properties of each function iteratively:

```
Object.keys(nestedObj)forEach(function(key){
 nestedObj[key].scale().domain([0,number])
}
```

Which results in obj1.scale being overwritten by obj2.scale, I think because the function is a shallow copy. `jQuery.extend(true)` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` don't seem to work. Is there any way around this without changing my general order of operations?

Thank you!

Comment: See the update to my answer, below. I think you have a different problem with the way you are setting and using `scale`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear that your application requires the cloning of a function, but there is a way to do that.

I've included a cloning function below.

```js
function cloneFunction (fn) {
  let fnStr = fn.toString();
  let fnClone = new Function('return ' + fnStr);
  return fnClone();
}

let myFunc = function (a) { return a * 2; }
console.log('myFunc(1):', myFunc(1));

let mfClone = cloneFunction(myFunc);
console.log('mfClone(2):', mfClone(2));
```

---

## Is this really a function cloning problem?

Is the issue truly a problem with cloning functions? Based on the information provided in the question, there seems to be a more fundamental problem.

The reported trouble item is `scale`:

```
scale: d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateGreens)
```

This expression sets the value of `scale` to the following function:

```js
function scale(x) {
  return isNaN((x = +x))
    ? unknown
    : interpolator(
        k10 === 0
          ? 0.5
          : ((x = (transform(x) - t0) * k10),
            clamp ? Math.max(0, Math.min(1, x)) : x)
      );
}
```

Then, at some later point, `scale` is invoked in this statement:

```
nestedObj[key].scale().domain([0,number)
```

which includes a call to `scale()` with no argument. That returns `undefined`, so `scale().domain([0,number)` produces a **TypeError**.

Here's a code snippet that shows the problem in action:

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');

function emitData() {
  let scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateGreens);
  result.innerHTML = 'scale.toString():\n' + '"' + scale.toString() +
    '"\n\n';
  result.innerHTML += 'scale() returns:\n' + scale();
  result.innerHTML += '\n\nscale().domain([0,1]) returns:\n';
  try {
    let test = scale().domain([0,1]);
    result.innerHTML += test;
  } catch (e) {
    result.innerHTML += '"' + e.toString() + '"';
  }
}
```

```css
pre {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 95%;
  min-height: 6rem;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p id="client">Testing "scale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateGreens)"</p>
<button onclick="emitData()">Run Test</button><br/>
<pre id="result"></pre>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-format.v1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v0.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time.v1.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: only works if there are no dependencies ... `a  = (b) => b + b; c = (d) => d * a(d);` will never work

Comment: @balexandre If you mean that `cloneFunction()` does a shallow copy of a function, that is true. It won't clone any function references within the target function.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a deep clone of your object like below:

```js
const obj = {a: 'a'};
const deepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```